# Finding matches around specific text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How can I find matches **just Around** text same as this:

```
if(strcmp(cmdtext, " /x ", true) == 0)

if(strcmp(cmdtext, " /y ", true) == 0)

if(strcmp(cmdtext, " /z ", true) == 0)
```

Basically, I want to find matches in this format: `if(strcmp(cmdtext, "` and `", true) == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure **Search Mode** is set to **Regular Expression** and **. matches newline** is *not* selected, either of the following should work:

```
if\(strcmp\(cmdtext, ".*?", true\) == 0\)
if\(strcmp\(cmdtext, " /. ", true\) == 0\)
```

If on the other hand you want to replace the middle section with something else (for example `/a`) and retain the left and right sections, use this:

**Search:** `(if\(strcmp\(cmdtext, ").*?(", true\) == 0\))`

**Replace:** `\1 /a \2`